# Return the beginning of a string up to and including either of two characters

Tags: r, regex

I have a character vector that looks like this:

```
a <- c("Bob/7", "What is this?", "Seventeen")
```

I want to extract the beginning of the string up to **and including** either a slash (`/`) or whitespace (). The result should look something like this:

```
b
[1] "Bob/"  "What " NA
```

The non-matching items can also be empty strings or dropped instead of returning `NA`.

I have tried with `grep("^.+?[/ ]", a, value = TRUE)`, but that returns the matching elements instead of the matching substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach using only `sub`:

```
a <- c("Bob/7", "What is this?", "Seventeen", "AA 1", "AA 7", " AA 7")
sub("(.*?[/ ]|).*", "\\1", a)
# [1] "Bob/"  "What " ""      "AA "   "AA "   " "
```

So, here `.*?[/ ]` is almost exactly what you had: I replaced `+` with `*` for cases like the last one in my `a` vector. Next, `|` corresponds to OR so that `a|b` matches `a` or `b`. Now having `.*?[/ ]|` matches what we want or, if it wasn't there, we match an empty string `""`. Without it we would get:

```
sub("(.*?[/ ]).*", "\\1", a)
# [1] "Bob/"      "What "     "Seventeen" "AA "       "AA "       " "
```

Namely, there was nothing to be done with `Seventeen`, so it remained unchanged, while with the actual solution we replace it with an empty string.

Comment: Nice! What does the pipe (`|`) mean?

Comment: @user57423, that's "or". E.g., `grep("a|b", c("a", "b", "c"))` returns `[1] 1 2`.

Comment: I see. And what does it do here? I don't understand why there is nothing to the right of the `OR`.

Comment: @user57423, that's the trick. Using your pattern with `gsub` wouldn't match anything at "Seventeen", but as a result would return the same "Seventeen". I'll update my answer with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

```
b <- regmatches(a, regexpr("^.+?[/ ]", a))
b
[1] "Bob/"  "What "
```